# Tab completion for non-file-system paths or URIs (e.g. gs://...)

Tags: google-cloud-storage, filesystems, cloud, tab-completion

I use cloud storage (eg gcs, s3) in addition to the local file system for data analysis.

My question is: are there tools that enable tab completion (in a shell environment) for file paths or URIs that aren't on local, mounted file systems? Eg for a file URI like `gs://path/to/file.txt`, I'd like to have tab completion when typing part of the path.

Note: I don't want to use FUSE (or `mount` a file system or volume in some way). I'm wondering if there are bash or zsh extensions that enable this functionality for non-file-system URIs, presumably with API calls in the background or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gcloud interactive` shell has auto-complete and auto prompting for any command that has a manual page, including the `gcloud`, `bq`, `gsutil`, and `kubectl` command-line tools.

To enable the `gcloud` interactive shell:

1. Install the `gcloud beta` components first by running the command `gcloud components install beta`.
2. Run `gcloud beta interactive` to enter gcloud interactive mode.

You can now use the `tab` to complete a file path or resource assignment

Check this link for the official documentation of [gcloud auto-complete](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/interactive-gcloud#auto-completion_and_help).

Comment: whoa. thank you! this is rad.